# Real time ingestion to Redshift without using S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, apache-nifi

I'm currenty using Apache NiFi to ingest realtime data using kafka, I would like to take this data to redshift to have a near real time transacction table for online analytics of campaign results and other sutff.

The catch, if I use Kinesis or copy from S3 I would have a LOT of read/writes from/to S3, I found on previous experiences that this becomes very expensive.

So, is there a way to send data to a redshift table without constant locking the destination table? the idea is putting the data directly from NiFi without persisting it. I have a hourly batch process so it would not be a problem if I lost a couple or rows on the on online stream.

Why redshift? that's the Data Lake platform and it will become handy to cross online data with other tables.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Firehose can stream to Redshift directly. Not sure if you considered that?

Comment: I was sure that firehose makes use of S3,. Great if not, all will happen "on memory"

Comment: I does not use S3. S3 is one of its possible destinations, just like redshift is.

Comment: Great, I don't remember where I read that firehose used S3 to put files and use the copy command from there, will test it, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes. If Firehose would suit your needs, I can provide an answer for future reference :-)